# Inheriting an inherited IRA from a spouse

Tags: united-states, ira, inheritance

If I inherit the following three IRAs from my spouse:

- Traditional IRA (no RMD yet taken/required; does that matter?)
- Roth IRA
- Inherited IRA (spouse inherited from parent)

what can I do with the inherited IRA?

Several sources (e.g. [Fidelity](https://www.fidelity.com/retirement-ira/inherited-ira/learn-about-your-choices), [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2019_publink1000230539)) indicate that I can treat the Traditional and Roth IRAs as my own and roll them into my existing IRAs. However, I can't find any direct answers about options for the inherited IRA. Does it need to be closed immediately? Can I slowly draw it down over some number of years (if so, based on my spouse's date of death? their parent's date of death? my life expectancy?)? Or since it comes from my spouse can I treat it as my own?

Comment: Presumably your spouse does not have the right to change the beneficiary of the IRA she inherits from her parent, and so you must have been named as the secondary beneficiary by her parent?

Comment: @DilipSarwate It sounds like you are implying the answer "it depends on what was specified by the original IRA owner". Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I found the following in an older copy of Pub. 590. "**Death of a beneficiary.** In general, the beneficiaries of a deceased beneficiary must continue to take the required minimum distributions after the deceased beneficiary’s death, based on the distribution schedule established by that beneficiary under the rules in the following paragraphs. The beneficiaries of a deceased beneficiary don't calculate required minimum distributions using their own life expectancies." So, you as a beneficiary of the deceased beneficiary (your spouse) must take RMDS as per her schedule.

Comment: In short, it seems that your spouse _can_ change the beneficiaries of the inherited IRA (her parent's original secondary beneficiaries are SOL unless your spouse chose to it leave it to them). And if she did/does nothing (including naming you as the beneficiary of the Inherited IRA), the secondary beneficiaries are still SOL since the Inherited IRA becomes part of her estate.